# Puppet: remote clients are not updated by puppetmaster

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, centos6.4

I'll start with the fact that I'm noob to Puppet, I have 2 servers; one is called puppetmaster and the other is called puppetclient.
I've installed puppet-3.2.2 and created some basic nodes.pp file, the nodes.pp file includes settings for both puppetmaster and puppetclient.
When i apply the relevant manifest the changes are only affecting the puppetmaster but not the client.
On the server I see the next error:

```
[root@puppetmaster puppet]# puppet apply manifests/nodes.pp 
hostname: Unknown host
dnsdomainname: Unknown host
hostname: Unknown host
dnsdomainname: Unknown host
hostname: Unknown host
dnsdomainname: Unknown host
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.71 seconds
[root@puppetmaster puppet]#
```

Even though a DNS server is configured on `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
While checking the puppetmaster log i see the next error:

```
[2013-08-08 11:03:00] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_accept returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read client certificate A: tlsv1 alert unknown ca
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:34:in `accept'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:34:in `listen'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:32:in `listen'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:31:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:31:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:31:in `listen'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:28:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:28:in `listen'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/server.rb:92:in `listen'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/server.rb:104:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/daemon.rb:137:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/master.rb:215:in `main'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/master.rb:165:in `run_command'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:364:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:456:in `plugin_hook'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:364:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util.rb:504:in `exit_on_fail'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:364:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:132:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:86:in `execute'
    /usr/bin/puppet:4
[root@puppetmaster ~]#
```

The puppet log on the client is blank. I investigated a little bit on the internet and saw that there's some command called `puppetca` in older version but as it seems, it's not part of the 3.2.2 version.
Anyone knows how to get it to work?

Comment: Any reason not to use the puppetlabs repository? using a recent puppet will be really helpful. Also, why webrick? IIRC that was deprecated quite a while back.

Comment: That's the repo i'm using: `baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/$releasever/products/$basearch/` , is it not the regular one?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be using the PuppetLabs Yum repositories - details [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#for-red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-derivatives).

---

Secondly, you should either be using Passenger or Mongel behind Apache - WEbrick is a very basic web-server and will not scale well beyond one or two nodes. Using Passenger is the most scalable option and is relatively easy to set up, so it should save you bundles of time in the long-run. Take a look at the [PuppetLabs Passenger docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/passenger.html) for more details.

Your DNS should be set up so that the CNAME `puppet.mydomain` (replacing `mydomain` with your FQDN) should point to your master - this is how nodes will automatically discover your master. If they cannot find `puppet.mydomain` and no further configuration is provided on either the CLI or in `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`, the nodes will not be able to contact the master.

When running Puppet on the master, you can use `puppet apply --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp` to bootstrap your master's configuration (Puppet can - and ideally should - be used to configure the master itself), and subsequent runs can be run by invoking either `puppet agent --test` or the `puppet apply` command above.

---

Thirdly, you should be using Puppet modules instead of adding configuration to `manifests/nodes.pp`. Take this example:

`manifests/nodes.pp`:

```
node mynode {
  include mymodule
}
```

`modules/mymodule/init.pp`:

```
class mymodule {
  file { '/path/to/some/file':
    ensure => file,
    owner  => 'myuser',
    group  => 'mygroup',
    mode   => '0755',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/myfile',
  }
}
```

In this example, your module will deploy the file, and your node definition within your manifest uses `include` to import the module into that node's manifest.

---

The `puppetca` command has been superceded by `puppet cert`. Once you have your master configured, you will need to use this command to sign your nodes' certificates. Example:

On node:`puppet agent --test` (generate the SSL certificate and ship it to the master)

On master: `puppet cert list` (to list the outstanding unsigned certificates)

On master: `puppet cert sign mynode.myfqdn` (to sign the node's certificate)

On node: `puppet agent --test` (to re-run Puppet, now that your node's certificate has been signed)